# Couchbase Sync Gateway - get previous revision of document?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I've got an android app using Couchbase lite as I need offline mode.

When I make multiple changes to a document on the device, the first sync'd document I get has a revision number greater than 1.

Is it possible to get previous revisions of that document?

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this was possible in some situations on 1.x, it is no longer possible as of 2.0.

Comment: So regardless of whether the document came from the device, it's not possible to view previous revisions of a document?

Comment: Correct, overall it was confusing when the revisions were not always availble